# Convert NSArray to Swift Array<T> and filter out Elements not matching T

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, nsarray

Converting `NSArray` to a Swift `Array` of Type `T` is easy, if all the elements are indeed of type `T` already:

```
let arr1 : NSArray = [1,2,3]
let arr2 = arr1 as? Array<Int> // works
```

But now assume a non-homogenous `NSArray` with objects that do not match `T`:

```
let arr1 : NSArray = [1,2,3,"a"]
let arr2 = arr1 as? Array<Int> // nil, as not all elements are of type Int
```

What I try to achieve is a downcast that filters out all elements not matching `T`. So in the above case I want to get an `Array<Int>` that contains the objects `[1,2,3]` only.

How to do that elegantly?

Comment: I'm not sure but could you create an `[Any]` and then filter it by type before casting to a `<T>` array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Condensed:

```
let arr1 : NSArray = [1,2,3,"a"]
let arr2 = (arr1 as Array<AnyObject>).filter { $0 is Int } as! Array<Int>
```

Step by step:

```
let arr2 = arr1 as Array<AnyObject>  // convert NSArray to Array of AnyObject
let arr3 = arr2.filter { $0 is Int } // keep only objects that are of type Int
let arr4 = arr3 as! Array<Int>       // force cast to Array<Int>, as now you know that all objects are of that type
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the one :D